# Kafka + IIS : Bad gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, apache-kafka

I have a kafka server running on a linux server 10.xx.xx.xx:9092. And i have a producer asp.net core 2.0 webapi application build in C# running on iis.

Getting bad gateway error

Kafka server is running on Linux box.

When i test the api in postman, getting the following error:

```
        <h3>HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway</h3>
        <h4>The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.</h4>
```

Comment: Make sure you are able to ping and the port is open

Comment: Yes. i am able to ping and telnet to the port as well.

Comment: check the entries in hosts file

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts doesn't have any entry for this ip. do i need to enter anything here? if so , can you let me know what it should look like ? thanks

Comment: if you are using internal ip thenit needs to be there

Comment: No this didnt helped. Same issue

Comment: Unclear what you tested in Postman... Kafka isn't an HTTP service. You need to look at your server logs

Comment: @cricket_007 I tested my producer , in my case it is a asp.net webapi. so tested the api in postman sending the json. there is nothing on the server logs. i guess the api is unable to talk to the linux server ip. but ping and telnet is working.

Comment: It's unclear what the question has to do with Kafka, though, if you're getting web server errors, but glad you fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the listeners property in server.properties made this work.

```
server.properties:

listeners=xx.xxx.xx.xx:9092
```